# Why isn't javafx.scene.text.Font Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, fonts, javafx-2, javafx

The old [java.awt.Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.File%29) is conveniently Serializable - however somewhat annoyingly, the [JavaFX font class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html) isn't. Even more annoyingly, it's awkward to serialize manually since the `FontPosture` and `FontWeight` objects specified in the constructor aren't available after construction (have to resort to calling and parsing `getStyle()` instead.) I'm struggling to think why this is the case, on the surface at least I certainly can't see any functionality present on the JavaFX Font not present on the AWT font that would be awkward to serialize.

Is there any technical reason why this is the case that I'm missing, or is it an API anomaly that could possibly be rectified in a future release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few things in JavaFX are serialized.  You can find out everything that is serializable by reviewing the [serialized-form](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/serialized-form.html) page of the javadoc.  With that, you can see that pretty much the only things which may be serialized are the events based on an old serializable [java.util.EventObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html) and the JFXPanel which integrates with Swing.  Everything else is not serializable.  So, it would be quite atypical for Font to be serializable when almost nothing else is.

JavaFX itself relies heavily on it's dynamic property mechanism and it's associated bindings and change listeners.  The underlying property system itself is (currently) not serializable, so that is one of the reasons why JavaFX does not have a lot of serialization in it.

That said, the Font object is rare in JavaFX in that it seems to be immutable, with just a constructor and getter methods provided and no properties used.  So it could theoretically be made serializable quite easily.  You could file a [feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) proposing this.  It may be treated as low priority though because JavaFX itself doesn't really rely on serialization much.  The serialization approach in the JavaFX implementation appears to be don't serialize unless necessary to integrate with existing apis or frameworks.

If you have further questions on serialization in JavaFX and the reasoning behind the framework not making much use of it, you could ask on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).  My guess is (similar to the warning Nick posts in his answer), that it was decided that blanket serialization support in the framework was a bad idea for numerous reasons, so a deliberate decision was made not to support it (but that's just a guess).

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested and filed a feature request - shall see what happens! https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31751

Comment: I think there will be limitations to deserialization of `Font` objects. That doesn't mean it shouldn't be Serializable, I'm just saying Deserialization can either not be guaranteed (font unavailable) or leads to a different (fallback) font.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has to do with serializable classes generally not being compatible between releases.  If the application relies on the UI being serializable, you could have some major problems between releases.  You can see the [warning on swing components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) about using serialization.

> Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeansTM has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder.

That said, I'll put my opinion here too.  To me, it messes with MVC separation to be serializing the UI (Granted there are other arcitectures out there too - MVC isn't a golden bullet).  It seems simpler to put the things you care about in a separate object;  You've already written the code to do the UI - if there's specific x/y coordinates it needs to be at, or the object should be focused on boot up, it makes sense just to save that information instead of every default color, listener, skin associated with the node.

You may have different needs - I don't know based on your question.  If you're looking for a way to load up the UI from a file (and not caring about saving), I'd recommend looking into FXML and CSS (I assume you already know about those things though)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - in my case I'm implementing a custom JavaFX DnD handler which moves an object which in turn contains a font, and for this to work the object needs to be serializable. So in my case, the compatibility between releases isn't an issue, though in some cases I can see how it might prove a problem.

Comment: Oh, sure.  I haven't been a fan of the DnD handlers - I can see their use if you're trying to move content between applications or JVMs, but otherwise (if it's in the same application), I very much prefer the Full Drag functionality.